# Login wallpaper

Tags: login-screen, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the wallpaper in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm)
>   [How do I return to default wallpaper on login screen in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134762/how-do-i-return-to-default-wallpaper-on-login-screen-in-12-04)

I know the desktop background wallpaper will also be displayed on the login screen. What would I need to set the login wallpaper separate from the desktop wallpaper? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I looked but didn't find anything. Thanks for the link. I did find the issue. At the top of the tweak window it says Unlock. Seems kind of odd to be out of the way. Oh well lol.

Comment: Which tweak window? Can you be more specific? It's hard to understand if this is the same question as linked or not.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I think, he is saying Ubuntu tweak's window. There is a unlock button in lightdm setting section. :)

Comment: @Nathan go to the link and read the answers again. I think, the help was there. Ubuntu tweak can't change this yet in 12.04. You need the terminal way to do so.

Comment: Sorry, but yes, inside the Ubuntu-Tweak window. I read through them all. Found that my lightdm conf file is empty. I looked at the links and through "How do I change the wallpaper in LightDM?" found an answer. Since the conf file is blank and the ppa gives a 404, I looked for the actual web site for simple-lightdm-manager. I was able to find the deb file. I downloaded that and it's working! Thanks everyone!