# LightDM Backgroud is a simple purple radiant

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background, ubuntu-tweak

It seems after I tried to change the login screen background with Ubuntu Tweak, the greeter's background stays a simple purple background with just the spots..

I tried using `dconf-editor`, rechanging the image from Ubuntu Tweak back to the default, it still does not work.

So In The End, everything for the `lightdm` points to  `/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png`.

But it's still a purple solid color. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the picture file you're trying to use does not have the proper permissions to be viewed by others. Since you are logging on in LightDM and not yet known, the system can not display files which are limited access.

To make a file accessible for the LightDM screen, right-click on the file in Nautilus and select `Properties`, then `Permissions` and make sure "Access" is **not** set to "*None*" for "Group" or "Others".

[image: Nautilus File Permissions tab]

Also note that the LightDM background defaults to the background of whatever user is highlighted in the log in space.

Comment: BTW, setting a user's background picture access to owner only is a way to intentionally have the default background on the LightDM screen as answered at http://askubuntu.com/questions/134762/how-do-i-return-to-default-wallpaper-on-login-screen-in-lightdm

Answer (score 0):

There's another thing to keep in mind. If the picture is not located in your `~/Pictures` folder, it will not work. Not even if you put it in a sub-directory of that folder.

I tried a lot of different possibilities, and the only one that works is to give both group and others at least Read-only access, place the image in your `Pictures` folder and change your background, selecting the `Pictures` folder from the dropdown box.

Logout, et voila, there's your background.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it has been a while.. I took a break from UNIX for a while.. And came back still frustrated.. I have done all things eferyone has reccomended and even uninstalled and reinstalled lightdm.. But still no good..

Is reinstalling ubuntu my only hope now?

Answer (score -1):

try to restart X Display: Manager:

```
sudo -s
setsid service lightdm restart
```

,maybe it will make  the difference
to restart unity and compiz to default

```
Restart Unity: setsid unity
Restart Compiz: setsid compiz --replace
```